# Jquery add CSS class after 'X' amount of viewport height scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, height

So I have this jQuery function that adds / removes a CSS class to an element after 600px of the viewport height has been scrolled.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();    
    if (scroll >= 600) {
        $(".cta_box").addClass('fadeout');
    } else {
        $(".cta_box").removeClass('fadeout');
    }
});
```

I'd like to tweak it so instead of working based off a pixel value, it works off of the view height css measurement "VH", but the equivalent results are what matter in this case.

Comment: How do you feel 600px should be converted into vh units? Should the result be a calculated absolute height - as with px - or should it be a viewport relative flexible amount?

Comment: Viewport relative flexible amount, the 600px value in this is arbitrary in the sense I rather replace it with a percentage based value so it scales responsively, I want this threshold to trigger after say, 20% or 40% the viewport has been scrolled by. I guess I could use an anchor div in a different approach, but I'd like to know if this is possible first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by getting the `window` height using `$(window).height()`.

For instance suppose you have to scroll half the screen more (height is 150vh) and you have to detect when 40% has been scrolled:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();    
    if (scroll >= 0.4 * $(window).height()) {
        $(".cta_box").addClass('fadeout');
    } else {
        $(".cta_box").removeClass('fadeout');
    }
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 150vh;
}
.cta_box {
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.cta_box.fadeout {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cta_box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a percentage of the window height to compare

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var height = $(window).height(),
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
        limit = 0.6; //implies 60 vh or 60% of viewport height

    if (scroll >= height*limit) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```

and even better would be to update some variable only when the window is resized to avoid computations all the time

```
var limit = 0.6, //implies 60 vh or 60% of viewport height
    scrollLimit = 0;

$(window).resize(function(){
          scrollLimit = $(window).height() * limit;
       }).scroll(function() {    
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 

          if (scroll >= scrollLimit ) {
              $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
              } else {
              $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
          }
       }).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll'); // trigger both events on start to force initial setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For retrieveing the viewport Height, you could use $(window).innerHeight():

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).innerHeight();        
    if (scroll >= 600) {
        $(".cta_box").addClass('fadeout');
    } else {
        $(".cta_box").removeClass('fadeout');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Leo.

Comment: But's that's still working with a fixed pixel amount correct?

Comment: Correct, the viewport height will always be the same, it will not change on scroll, but in there you are checking for each time the scrolls happens, then it checks against the viewport Height.