# How do I keep a div hidden when window is scrolled to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an up arrow that fades in when my page is scrolled down. How can I make it so that it fades out when the user scrolls back to the top of the page?

This is what I have so far. The arrow will disappear for a brief second then fade back in which I don't want - it should stay hidden.

```js
function footerFadeIn() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('footer').fadeIn('slow');
  });
}

function footerFadeOut() {
  $('footer').fadeOut('slow');
  $('footer').hide();
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    footerFadeOut();
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    footerFadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-up" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>
</footer>
```

My thought process here is to have two functions - `footerFadeIn()` and `footerFadeOut()`. Then I have an if statement that checks if the window is scrolled away from scrollTop() of zero and executes the respective function.

**EDIT:** My question differs from the suggested one in that I simply had two event handlers that were causing the issue.

Comment: Your `footerFadeIn` function doesn't fade in but add an additional scroll handler to the window. Fix that (your `footerFadeOut` is fine) and it should work as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery add CSS class after 'X' amount of viewport height scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193912/jquery-add-css-class-after-x-amount-of-viewport-height-scrolled)

Comment: @chrisG Wow. Thank you. I feel silly now for how long I spent trying to figure that out. I apprecaite your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you have added a scroll event handler inside `footerFadeIn()`. As such you end up creating another new scroll event handler when a scroll event happens. To fix this, just remove the scroll handler in that function and leave the main one which is called when the DOM loads.

Also note that you need to call `hide()` in the callback of `fadeOut()`. This is why the fadeout animation doesn't happen correctly. Try this:

```js
function footerFadeIn() {
  $('footer').fadeIn('slow');
}

function footerFadeOut() {
  $('footer').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    footerFadeOut();
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    footerFadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" />
<footer>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-up" style="font-size: 35px;"></i>
</footer>
```

Comment: @DMellon If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Sanguinary will do! It's just telling me I have to wait another five minutes before doing so.