# CSS/JS Add class to div when page is scrolled to a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to add a class to a div when the page is scrolled to a certain point.

*The  important parts of my CSS:*

```css
.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6.5vh;
}

.top-bar-bg {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg,#6272e9,#36104a);  
}
```

I've tried adding the class (`top-bar-bg`) using

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event){
var scroll = this.scrollY;
if(scroll > 860) {
   this.document.getElementById("nav").classList.add("top-bar-bg");
} else {
   this.document.getElementById("nav").classList.remove("top-bar-bg");
}
});
```

to then notice that when I zoom in or out, scrollY will be different values so the class is added to early/late.

I've also tried doing [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40194078/13484433) only to realize that it gives me the same issue.

Am I missing something (obvious)?
Or is this not the right way to do it?
If you know how to do it, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified the code and totally revamped it.

```js
$(function(){
    var btn = $('.button');
    var btnPosTop = btn.offset().top;
    var win = $(window);
    win.scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop >= btnPosTop){
            //we've reached the button
            btn.css({position:'fixed',top:0,marginTop:0});
        }else if(btn.css('position') === 'fixed'){
            //if we scroll back up past the button's original position, and the button had previously been changed to its fixed position, we change it back
            btn.css({position:'',top:'',marginTop:'100px'});
        }
    });
});
```

Anyway, you should put the code for making the text appear inside of the `if(scrollTop >= btnPosTop)` statement. Just like the button, it should get a position of fixed (either by setting it in JS or by adding a class to the containing div that has its CSS specified as having `position:fixed`) so that it moves along as the page scrolls.

Fiddle: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/Zte6T/1/)

Comment: Rewriting that the way you mentioned isn't a problem. But that doesn't fix my issue because the problem, that the class is added to early (which is important that it doesn't because it's a menu bar) still persists when I zoom out, because win.scrollTop(); gets larger faster the more the page is zoomed out: If I scroll to the point where it needs to change with 100% zoom scrollTop is 969, when I do that with a 50% zoom it's 1836. But because the offset remains the value, the class is already added at half the "scroll-way".

Answer (score -1):

is this what you were looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
         $('.box').addClass('box-hover');
      } else {
         $('.box').removeClass('box-hover');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
color: red;
}

.box:hover {
color: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">1</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<!-- After scroll down add class box-hover-->
<div class="box box-hover">1</div>
```

Comment: I don't need it to change when I hover over it, read my comment to Theodores reply for a detailed explanation on what my problem is.